# ttkwidgets Calendar button language

Tags: python, tkinter, calendar, ttkwidgets

I want to know, if it is possible to change the language of the buttons "previous" and "next". If I change "locale" the monthsnames only are changed but not the buttons.
thank you in advance.

Comment: if you are talking of changing text of buttons then you can use `mybutton.config(text="previous")`

Comment: Basically no because the two strings are hard-coded inside the source of `ttkwidgets`.

Answer (score 0):

The text of buttons is hard-coded and the buttons are not attributes of the calendar so it is not easy to change their texts. However, it is possible to create a custom class inheriting from `ttkwidgets.Calendar` and just rewrite the function `__place_widgets()` where the buttons are defined:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkwidgets

translation = {"Previous": "Précédant", "Next": "Suivant"}

def _(string):
    return translation.get(string, string)


class Calendar(ttkwidgets.Calendar):
    def __place_widgets(self):
        # header frame and its widgets
        hframe = ttk.Frame(self)
        lbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, command=self._prev_month, text=_("Previous"))
        rbtn = ttk.Button(hframe, command=self._next_month, text=_("Next"))
        self._header = ttk.Label(hframe, width=15, anchor='center')
        # the calendar
        self._calendar = ttk.Treeview(self, show='', selectmode='none', height=7)

        # pack the widgets
        hframe.pack(side='top', pady=4, anchor='center')
        lbtn.grid(sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.W + tk.E)
        self._header.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=12)
        rbtn.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.S + tk.W + tk.E)
        self._calendar.pack(expand=1, fill='both', side='bottom')



root = tk.Tk()
cal = Calendar(root, locale="fr_FR.UTF-8")
cal.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

which gives a calendar in French [image: screenshot]